# Transaction still unconfirmed after 2 days

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

Last time I tried sending a transaction with the minimum fee it was succesful after 1 day. 2 days ago i tried sending one with a higher fee and double the bitcoin amount but its still unconfirmed.
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/7e3e62569bb24f029ddce8730320bd2dbce10bc6893e4c117f5c49be18c96cf1

Answer (score 2):

An unconfirmed transaction will eventually be accepted into a block by whichever mining pool mines the block, or the transaction will eventually be rejected by the bitcoin network after an estimated one to seven days. If it eventually is rejected, then the funds would remain at the bitcoin address they were sent from. The only thing you can do at this point is to wait and see if the transaction is accepted into a block. Like all wallet providers, Blockchain.info has absolutely no control over this, and cannot expedite transactions. This is always dependent upon the bitcoin network of miners, which we are not a part of.

Blockchain.info wallets utilize dynamic fees. The following link explains how this works - https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/03/16/introducing-dynamic-fees/.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Many people have this same question, and we are trying to direct them to a single question where we can collect all answers and avoid people wasting their time saying what has already been said.  See the "Possible duplicate" comment above.  Also, in general you should only post one answer to a question.  If you have more information to add, use the "edit" button to update your existing answer.  I would suggest you edit one of your answers and delete the others.

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin mempool is currently backlogged, which is causing a delay with transaction confirmations. You can follow it live on this chart, which shows all pending bitcoin transactions on the bitcoin network - https://blockchain.info/charts/mempool-count. This is impacting the entire bitcoin network, not just Blockchain.info.